# undefined method Cake\Utility\Security::cipher()

Tags: cakephp, encryption

I am trying to create users management modal. I am using this code

```
      $encryptKey = 'ab12333way2code';
      $secret = Security::cipher('StringToEncrypt', $encryptKey);
```

But it's showing the following Fatal error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method has been removed in CakePHP 3.0

> Security::cipher() has been removed. It is insecure and promoted bad cryptographic practices. You should use Security::encrypt() instead.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#security